# C++ shared libraries with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, linker, shared

I have a library (a.so) with a base classes (MyClassA). Another library (b.so) has a class MyClassB that inherits from MyClassA (in a.so). I compile MyClassA.h and MyClassA.cpp isolated in a.so. MyClassB.h and MyClassB.cpp are compiled in isolation (with a reference to MyClassA.h but without adding MyClassA.h to b.so). I then link b.so to a.so.

To summarize:

1. a.so contains MyClassA.h and MyClassA.cpp
2. b.so contains MyClassB.h and MyClassB.cpp
3. b.so is linked to a.so

When I try to compile, I get a number of reference errors to MyClassA, caused by b.so.

When I compile b.so and add MyClass.h to it, the library compiles and runs without any errors. Hence:

1. a.so contains MyClassA.h and MyClassA.cpp
2. b.so contains MyClassB.h, MyClassB.cpp AND MyClassA.h
3. b.so is linked to a.so

Is it possible in C++ to use my first option, or is it required to always include the base headers in subclass library?

Comment: As first option should work we need to see more of the errors and code especially the headers and what they include

Answer (score 3):

If you derive `ClassB` from `ClassA` you should have your `ClassA` *defined*, when deriving, not only *declared* (*referenced*). That is why you have to include `ClassA` header file.

But if you implemented `ClassA` functions in `cpp` file, not in header, actual *code* of `ClassA` will be in `a.so`, so, includeing `ClassA` header file is not really a problem.

Comment: The only problem is that there are a lot of headers in a.so that I use in b.so. And when I add the headers to b.so, the size of b.so drastically increases (even though only the headers and not the cpp files are included). I was wondering if there is a way around this so that I can keep b.so very small. After all, the headers are already in a.so

Comment: Check if your headers contains _code_, like function _defenitions_ (not _declarations_), or may be some template usages, you can try reduce public headers size by using `pimpl` or `facade` patterns

Comment: My base class headers have a LOT of pure virtual function decelerations in them, no implementation. That's what makes the headers so big. If I have 50 sub-libraries inheriting from classes in a.so, then the header data from the classes in a.so (lets say 100kb) is duplicated in every of the 50 sub-libraries. Thats 50x100kb = almost 5mb of duplicated headers that are actually already in a.so

Comment: Heh, you can't count like that. Most of that 100kb probably is runtime dependencies, well, if you write 'hello world' you can get 50kb, but it means noting.

Comment: Joh, know that. Just wondering if there is a trick on telling b.so not to include the headers directly, but automatically pull them from a.so during runtime?

Comment: headers contatins _metada_ mostly, which does not comiles to any code, that could increase your program size. Just, don't worry about that. If you use `g++` just print `gcc hello_world.cpp`, where `hello_world.cpp`, is a program that prints `hello_world` with `cout`. It printes out 425KB of headers in my case.

Answer (score 0):

All derived classes must `#include` base class declarations in compilation time. Base class implementation must be known in linking time.

In your case:

1. a.so contains MyClassA.h and MyClassA.cpp
2. b.so contains MyClassB.h and MyClassB.cpp but MyClassB.h `#include "MyClassA.h"
3. b.so links a.so using:

g++ -o b.so -la

Comment: exactly what I did. The #include "MyClassA.h" is in the header MyClassB. Thats not the problem. The problem is that I actually have to include MyClassA.h inside b.so. This drastically increases the library size. I thought the linker(compiler) will look at the header file while building, but I don't have to actually add MyClassA.h to b.so. When I do this, I get referencing errors.

Comment: Really, you don't need to include MyClassA.h inside b.so. Show us, both MyclassA.h and MyClassB.h and compilation and linking commands.

Comment: I don't include it, the COMPILER does. I've checked: if I add some strings to the headers of MyClassA and compile MyClassB (b.so), then the size of b.so increases. So the compiler automatically pulls MyClassA.h to b.so. I'm currently using CMake, busy creating a simple example with normal g++ compiling

Comment: If uploaded a test example. If you un-comment line 13 in MyClassA.h, both liba.so and libb.so increase in size. I'm fine with the increasing size of liba.so, but I want to have a constant size of libb.so, no matter what changes in MyClassA.h.

Comment: http://hotfile.com/dl/143410240/e1ef096/test.zip.html  http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=51643

Answer (score 0):

If `class B` is a derived from `class A`, then the `class A` header file must be included.